# Get content from <p> paragraph in asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to load multiline textbox from paragraph of a web page with this code:

```
// load page source 
var cli = new WebClient();
string rawdata = cli.DownloadString(urltxt.Text.Trim());

// get paragraph content and load in textbox
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(rawdata);

foreach (HtmlNode paragraph in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    string content = paragraph.InnerText;
    valuetxt.Text = "";
    valuetxt.Text = content;
}
```

The problem I have: this code only returns the last paragraph of a web page, but I want all paragraphs. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you're overwriting the value the Text value each time. You need to build the content in the loop and then set the Text property outside it:

```
string content = "";

foreach (HtmlNode paragraph in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    content += paragraph.InnerText;
}

valuetxt.Text = content;
```

Comment: Thanks SBFrancies

Comment: Just to note, I'd agree with Paritosh that using a StringBuilder could be preferable - especially if there a lot of paragraphs.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `StringBuilder` here for better performance.

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(rawdata);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (HtmlNode paragraph in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    sb.Append(paragraph.InnerText);
}

valuetxt.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Reference and explanation: [String Vs StringBuilder C#](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/builder.html)

It's not just about making things work, it's about doing it perfectly!

Comment: Except form the correctness of your answer, for mentioning `StringBuilder` (+1)